# Update part of document in Elasticsearch from Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have multiple Kafka Connectors and Topics that all house different sources of data, yet all contain reference to the same primary key (lets call "id"). Can you update Elasticsearch using this same id?

For example, source 1 has the following schema

```
{
    "id": 123
    "some_value": "yo"
    "details": {}
}
```

Source 2 has the following

```
{
    "id": 123
    "reference": 1
},
{
    "id": 123
    "reference": 2  
}
```

Is there a way I can create my expected outcome within ES to mimic the following

```
{
    "id": 123
    "some_value": "yo"
    "details": [
        {
            "id": 123
            "reference": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 123
            "reference": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried using Kafka's transforms with hoistfield but have been unsuccessful

Comment: Each unique message offset from Kafka will creates one unique document in the Elastic index. Therefore, to get that output in Elastic, you need some Kafka producer that aggregates that data before Connect ever sees it.

Comment: I think the optimum solution would be to leverage ksql with kafka in order to group all the data together, but the two sources could be too far apart and could pass the data retention set within kafka.

Comment: @cricket_007 if you set the kafka sink's insert.mode to upsert, and provide your own index, then you can use the index provided from your origin data source as the ID within elasticsearch

Comment: @cricket_007 so I'm hoping the first data source creates the initial record within ES, then the second sink adds data to that same document by the ID

Comment: Well, you're seeming to want to turn `details` from an Elastic `object` mapping to a `array` (you cannot have a object within an object without a key for each value). I'm not too sure the index mapping will be happy about that

Comment: @cricket_007 That was a typo, definitely meant details to be an array